# UMDF, cannot specify [ClassInstall32] section for Microsoft-defined class

Tags: c++, drivers, wdm, kmdf, umdf

I'm working with the next tutorial: [How to write your first USB client driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh706184(v=vs.85).aspx).

And I've got a problem with compiling a project, I've got the next error:

[image]

I was trying to do the steps closely to the description in tutorial, but always got the error above, when compiling the project.

Also, I've tried to search, but didn't find any useful information.

Possible additional info, which might help you to give me a piece of advice:

- INF-file: http://pastebin.com/71d6bbQm
- Using Windows 10, latest WDK and VS2015
- Have started exactly `USB User-Mode Driver` template as was mentioned in tutorial

Comment: I removed this error by removing that part of the INF file, specifically: First line: `[ClassInstall32]` Second Line: `AddReg = ClassInstall_AddReg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the error is saying you're trying to create a class that already exist, which is the **USBDevice** class. Since you're trying to create a new USB client driver, you can go ahead and delete the **Class definition** section.

However, if you are trying to create a new class, then make sure that the class name and GUID don't already exist in this list: [System-Defined Device Setup Classes Available to Vendors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you want to learn more about INF files, check out this article: [INF Files for Bears of Little Brain](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/InfFiles.htm).

Comment: Sadly, that last link is now gone, and archive.org doesn't have a backup. Too bad; it looked really promising. This looks like another copy: http://azius.com/blog/inf-files-bear/